# Disable ALL dropdownlist with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to disable all inputs until the user performs some action.

```
$('input[type=text]').attr('readonly', true);
$('input[type=select]').attr('disabled', true);
```

This works fine for the textboxes but doesn't affect the dropdown list. Is it the type or something else? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by dropdowns? Like a 'select' tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` for this. Besides `select` is not an `input` but a separate tag:

```
$('select').prop('disabled', true);
```

Also you can simply use `:input` selector to reference all inputs in one go. This will cover both `input` and `select`:

```
$(':input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP mean select by dropdowns?

Comment: Thank you. In my case I want to keep them separate as I want to be able to easily read the textbox (not have it greyed out). It is obvious to my user why they would not be able to edit anything